# CSS--how to detect screen aspect ratio and apply styling accordingly?

Tags: html, css

first off, is there a way I can switch to the 4:3 aspect ratio for testing on Windows? I cant seem to find anything online. My monitor has a 16:9 aspect ratio but my alignment changes using CSS and HTML dont work to good on a screen with a 4:3 ratio. So is there a way to auto-detect aspect ratio and then apply the css/html styles accordingly? And more importantly, can I change my screens aspect ratio to 4:3 for testing? Is that even possible?

I'm aligning some images and other elements using margin/padding/ left/right/top bottom etc but the elements either get cut off or dont show on the screen at all.

thanks

Comment: Look into CSS media queries... it looks like what you are looking for

Comment: There is a media query for device aspect ratio: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#device-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing i would recommend using Firefox and use the Responsive Design View. You can find this option under Tools > Web Developer > Responsive Design View. Besides some predetermined resolution sizes you can also modify a custom view in a 4:3 perspective so you can check out the device aspect ratio as mentioned by Jonathan.